# style not getting applied

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made style with following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">          
        <item name="android:layout_width">150dip</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And applied it as:

```
 <EditText
  style="CodeFont"
  android:id="@+id/txt_username"
  android:inputType="textPersonName" >
  <requestFocus />
  </EditText>
```

but its not getting applied.

If i write same style in as:

```
              <EditText
               android:id="@+id/txt_username"
               android:layout_width="150dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
               android:ems="10"             
               android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Then it gets applied.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper way to set the style is:

```
style="@style/CodeFont"
```

For more info check the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Also check styles.xml

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
 **themes.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="ijoomer_theme" parent="define your parent theme here">
    <item name="edittext">@style/CodeFont</item>
</style>
</resources>

**attrs.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr name="edittext" format="reference" />
</resources>

**style.xml**
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">150dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
</style>
</resources>

**use edittext style**
<EditText
    style="?CodeFont" // this way you use your custom style
    android:id="@+id/txt_username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```